# Create Sub Array using Javascript - Dynamic

Tags: javascript

```
var array1 = [1,2,3...] //dynamic array
var array2 = [1,2,3...] //dynamic array
var array3 = [1,2,3...] //dynamic array

var Data= { 
        Finalarray = [{Array1: array1[0], Array2: array2[0], Array3:array3[0]},
                      {Array1: array1[1], Array2: array2[1], Array3: array3[1]}
                      {Array1: array1[2], Array2: array2[2], Array3: array3[2]}],
        Test="test"}
```

this is array1[] is dynamic array, how can we create final array patter dynamically as the array1[] can have many number of elements

Comment: Not clear what requirement is.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understood you right, there will always be 3 arrays but you dont know how many members will be in each array. If the arrays are all the same length, you can use `Array.prototype.map` over one and use the current index to get the members from the other two.

```js
var array1 = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5];
var array2 = [5, 4, 3, 2, 1];
var array3 = [3, 5, 1, 4, 2];

var Data = {
  Finalarray: array1.map(function(n, i) {
    return { Array1: n, Array2: array2[i], Array3: array3[i] };
  }),
  Test: "test"
};

console.log(Data);
```

Comment: It looks like the only change you made was to where the result is stored. I'll update the solution to reflect that change.

Comment: I updated the answer. It is still the same map solution but the result is stored in the property of `Data` instead.

Comment: Thank you :) You saved my precious time :) Can i have the source, where i can learn more about it :)

Comment: Yes, you can read the documentation for map here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map

Answer (score 2):

I think what you are looking for is the `.map()` function. You can do it like so:

```js
var array1 = [1,2,3] //dynamic array
var array2 = [2,3,4] //dynamic array
var array3 = [3,4,5] //dynamic array

var Finalarray = array1.map(function (element, index) {
  return {
    Array1: element,
    Array2: array2[index],
    Array3: array3[index]
  };
});

console.log(Finalarray);
```